# Gnuplot, how I get the length of an value?

Tags: gnuplot, strlen

I want to know the number of characters of a value.

but strlen ( ) is only for strings , not for values.
(  strlen(value("zon")) does not work)

Example: zon = 12000, len value is 5.

Is this possible with gnuplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of digits of a numerical value, use `log10` and round the value up:

```
zon = 12000
digits = int(ceil(log10(zon)))
print digits
```

prints `5`, as requested.

Comment: I have been at least five days searching and look at this, this works perfectly . Thanks

Comment: @con unfortunately, this doesn't work perfectly. Try `print int(ceil(log10(100)))` which will return `2`, which is not correct, but should be `3`.

Answer (score 6):

In some situations you may prefer to see how long a number is when it is printed:

```
zon = 12000
print strlen(sprintf("%d", zon))
```

This also prints 5.

Comment: This also works very well, even " n = strlen ( sprintf ( "% d " , sun) ) ," also thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result of the two questions I have placed;

- Is it possible to get the values for de y-axis in gnuplot?
- how I get the length of an value?

The reason was, I wanted a value in the columns where possible.
Here are the results and then the pieces of scripts that were needed.

Here the graphic;
[image: example]
And here the pieces of script;

```
set terminal unknown
plot "<tail -24 uur.txt" using 1:(-$7) w p, '' u 1:4 w p
ymax= GPVAL_Y_MAX
ymin= GPVAL_Y_MIN
ptmax=ymax*dy/(ymax-ymin)
ptmin=ymin*dy/(ymax-ymin)
replot
```

And;

```
"<tail -24 uur.txt" u ($1-600):4:( $4>0 && ($4/ymax*ptmax)> (10 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $4))) ? $4 : sprintf("")) w labels right rotate font ",8" tc rgb "white" offset 0,-0.1 notitle,\
"<tail -24 uur.txt" u ($1-600):4:( $4>0 && ($4/ymax*ptmax)<=(10 * strlen(sprintf("%d", $4))) ? $4 : sprintf("")) w labels  left rotate font ",8" tc rgb "black" offset 0,0.1  notitle,\
```

Thanx all for the solutions, its now perfect, it works by every scale.